# PHP Connect to Sharepoint using Thybag\SharePointAPI

Tags: php, sharepoint

I have the following code

```
//$sp = new SharePointAPI('&&', '&&', 'https://&&.net/personal/zzz/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL',);

//$sp = new SharePointAPI('&&', '&&', 'https://&&net/personal/zzz/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?SDL', 'NTLM');

$sp = new SharePointAPI('&&', '&&', 'https://&&net/personal/zzz/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL', 'SPONLINE');

$listContents = $sp->read('GetListCollection'); 

return $listContents;
```

Depending on which of the "new SharepointAPI" lines I execute, I get a different error.

Using "NTLM", I get the error: -

```
Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error'  
in /home/shinksyc/public_html/sharepointUpload/src/Thybag/Auth/SoapClientAuth.php:129
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Thybag\Auth\SoapClientAuth->__doRequest('<?xml 
version="...', 'https://my.sp.m...', 'http://schemas....', 1, 0)
```

Using "SPONLINE", I get the error

```
'Error (Client) looks like we got no XML document'.
```

I am also slightly confused as to how to find out what the name of the lists may be that I get read.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Martin

Comment: Just to clarify, the '&&' '&&' in your code sample has been replaced to the username and password right?

Comment: it has...same for the URL.

Comment: What type of SharePoint (SharePoint online vs self hosted) are you trying to connect to? Plus any idea what version it is. For self hosted in most cases you'll just want to use the basic auth method (the top) one, while for SharePoint online you'll want the SPOnline one.

Comment: It is a self hosted SP server. Using the top method is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The path to your xml must be local: in clear, log to your sharepoint, go to the url https://mySPsite/subsite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL
Download the XML and place it on your PHP server.
then

```
$sp = new SharePointAPI($login, $password, $localPathToWSDL, 'NTLM');
```